# Median by Year in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have longitudinal data for thirty companies, and I want to create a trend line of the median company by year. Currently, I have a separate row in the file for each year of the company. For example:

```
+-----------+------+-------+
| Name      | Year | Value |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Company A | 2014 | 2000  |
| Company A | 2013 | 2500  |
| Company B | 2014 | 3000  |
| Company B | 2013 | 2900  |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

I am imagining a graph that has year on the X axis and the value on the Y axis, with the data point being the median of all companies in a given year. What is the best way to do this? I have tried a number of things and still have not had any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to see a chart that shows the median value for each year as well as the company that had that median value. Here's one way:

Make a calculated field to find the median value per year (let's call it `Median Value per Year`):

```
{ FIXED [Year] : MEDIAN(Value) }
```

Next make a calculated field to find the company which had that median value (let's call it `Median Company`):

```
ATTR(
  IF [Median Value per Year] = [Value]
  THEN [Name]
  ELSE NULL
  END
)
```

That `IF` statement checks to see if the `Value` is equal to the median value we calculated earlier. If so, it returns the `Name`. Otherwise, `NULL`. When we take the `ATTR()` of that, it will ideally<sup>1</sup> return the name of the company which had that median value.

Now you can place `Year` in the columns shelf, `MEDIAN(Value)` in the Rows shelf, and (for example) put `AGG(Median Company)` in Label.

<sup>1</sup> If you have more than one company with that same value, then it will return "*".

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This is great. I was only asking for the first half of what you did, but the second bit will come in useful later! Just starting to learn Tableau and it is a really powerful tool.

Comment: One more question. If I wanted to exclude a company for a specific year from the calculation, what would be the easiest way?

Comment: FYI, you can leave off the "ELSE NULL" part from the calculated field if you wish. That is the implicit behavior when the if condition is not met.

Comment: The following link describes how filters interact with LOD calculations http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.html